# ruby on rails saving record create problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am facing the below error when saving the record into database after I added the new column to migration that is "fathername"

```
 NoMethodError in StudentController#admission1

undefined method `fathername=' for #<User:0x7ffcd42a3a40>

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:255:in `method_missing'
/root/ansipro342/app/models/student.rb:141:in `create_user_and_validate'
/root/ansipro342/app/controllers/student_controller.rb:62:in `admission1'

Request

Parameters:

{"student"=>{"first_name"=>"Salman",
 "fatheroccupation"=>"Lecturer",
 "address_line1"=>"",
 "address_line2"=>"",
 "country_id"=>"141",
 "roll_num"=>"100",
 "is_email_enabled"=>"1",
 "gender"=>"m",
 "fathernic"=>"",
 "biometric_id"=>"",
 "admission_date"=>"2015-12-11",
 "date_of_birth"=>"2010-12-11",
 "fathername"=>"Kamran",
 "nationality_id"=>"141"}
```

even the fathername column already exists but its showing the error pls help, I dont know what is wrong?

Comment: Have you added `fathername` in strong_parameters ? I assume you are using Rails 4.

Comment: add details of student_controller.rb ??@Naveed

Comment: no I dont know how to add in strong_parameters and I am using rails 2.3.5

Comment: did you restart your local server? ,, if yes post your all the codes including the model and controller.

Comment: yes I restarted and posted controller code

Comment: It has nothing to do with strong parameters - not including the param would just mean that the attribute is not set. I'm guessing that you have forgot to actually run the migration `rake db:migrate`.  ActiveRecord creates getters and setters in models based on the columns actually present in the db which is why you are getting a `NoMethodError`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to run the migrations `rake db:migrate` ! This is typically happening when you try to set an attribute value and this attribute column doesn't exists in the database.

Hope it helps :)